# Angular 2 Unit Test. Test Route with login screen and hidden menu component

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular2-testing

I have to realise Angular 2 unit Test on routes and I fail with errors.

My application start with that content within app.component.html

```
<app-top-menu></app-top-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have those routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'Second', component: SecondComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'Third', component: ThirdComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'Fourth', component: FourthComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

When you acccess the application you're first redirected toward a login page for authentification.
All other page can only be accessed if logged.

Within app.component.html we first have app-top-menu before router-outlet.
The component app-top-menu is hidden and appear only once the user is logged.
This tricked has been made to hide the app-top-menu component from login page.

When we log in login component we do that action to display the component app-top-menu

```
this.globalEventsManager.showNavBar(true);
```

Everyting works fine when I run ng serve - I use angular cli.
The UI is working very well.
But when I run ng test I get a first error in app.component

```
AppComponent should create the app
Failed: Template parse errors:
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<app-top-menu></app-top-menu>
[ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>"): AppComponent@1:0
```

then a second within SecondComponent about routerLink.

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>You're logged in with JWT!!</p>   
    <p><a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/login']">Logout</a></p>
</div>"): SecondComponent@3:10
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
```

Here is the content of my app.component.spec.ts

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
          AppComponent,
          TopMenuComponent
        ]      
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

How can I mock the router and test routes.
Also the app-top-menu is involved as it appears/disappear according to login.

Thanks for your help.